# ViewModel e delegates - Kotlin/Android

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

Galera, comecei a estudar Android a pouco tempo e em um dos projetos que estudo, fiquei com uma dúvida com relação a instância de ViewModel e delegates.

Partindo do pressuposto que, estou utilizando uma única ViewModel e que esta é compartilhada entre fragments, qual seria a melhor maneira de instanciar ela?

No meu último projeto eu usei essa linha de código:

```
private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel
```

No qual no código, já no onCreateView eu usava essa linha para atribuir o valor

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity())[MainViewModel::class.java]
```

Porém, eu observei o uso de delegates por outras pessoas para instanciar VM, no qual eu estou usando assim agora:

```
private val viewModel: MainViewModel by lazy { ViewModelProvider(requireActivity())[MainViewModel::class.java] }
```

E vi gente, utilizando algo como:

```
private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels()
```

Para mim, que quero compartilhar a VM entre os fragments, poderia usar o 'by ViewModels()'?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar activityViewModels para que usando delegates o ViewModel também tenho o escopo da Activity.

Comment: Muito obrigado, não sabia sobre o 'activityViewModels'.